# Spectum Colorpicker input[type='text'] not working when IE is switched to 10 and older versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, spectrum

I'm using Spectrum Colorpicker, which is pretty awesome javascript plugin.
It works perfectly with Chrome and FF and IE 11.
But when I switch to IE 10 and older,
The input='text' elements stop showing their beautiful skin.

the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../includes/spectrum.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' href="../../includes/spectrum.css" />
```

the html code:

```
<tr><td>
    Main Color
</td>
<td>
    <input type='text' id="CP_mainColor" />
</td>

<td>
    Sub Color
</td>
<td>
    <input type='text' id="CP_subColor" />
</td>
```

for jQuery
i cut some codes 'cause it's too long.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//Main Color
        $("#CP_mainColor").spectrum({
            chooseText: "Choose",
            cancelText: "Cancel",
            color: main_color,
            showInput: true,
            change: function (color) {

                // remove # from color hex
                var hfHexString = color.toHexString().replace("#", "");

                //Assign on hfHeaderFontColor
                console.log("hfMainColor value assigned :" + hfHexString);
            }
        });
        //Sub Color
        $("#CP_subColor").spectrum({
            chooseText: "Choose",
            cancelText: "Cancel",
            color: sub_color,
            showInput: true,
            change: function (color) {

                // remove # from color hex 
                var hfHexString = color.toHexString().replace("#", "");

                //Assign on hfHeaderFontColor
                console.log("hfSubColor value assigned :" + hfHexString);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you have?

Comment: sure, will edit the question.

Comment: hi rink, I've added the codes. :)

Comment: Well, it is solved.

I was trying to change the Emulation settings hoping it would be fixed then in random move, I changed the browser profile from Desktop to Windows Phone. Then I found out it is working in Windows Phone mode until IE 7 (as Spectrum supports until IE 6). So that I changed back to Desktop mode and it works!

Took about 3hr time, what can I say... It's IE. 

(=_=)'